# How do I run a patch for MacRuby

Tags: ruby, llvm, macruby

I ran into an error trying to install MacRuby related to llvm and found a patch for the specific problem but have no idea how to apply the patch.

The error is

```
    In file included from main.cpp:8:
llvm.h:21:38: error: llvm/Analysis/DIBuilder.h: No such file or directory
In file included from vm.h:594,
                 from main.cpp:17:
```

And the patch I found was
[Could not compile with LLVM 2.8 in r5276.](http://www.macruby.org/trac/ticket/1193)

Now that I have the patch file, what do I run to apply it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That patch looks simple enough that you *could* simply apply it by hand -- remove the lines starting with `-` and add the lines starting with `+` -- but that's only necessary if there are enough changes that the patch won't apply cleanly.

Because a patch file can be generated in different ways, it can also be applied in different ways:

```
diff -u a a.fixed > fix_compile.diff
patch < fix_compile.diff

diff -u dir1/a dir2/a > fix_compile.diff
patch -p1 < fix_compile.diff

diff -u dir1 dir2 > fix_compile.diff
patch -p1 < fix_compile.diff
```

If the fixed file is six directories down in the hierarchy, you either need to try applying the patch six directories up, or use a `-p6` or similar option to strip off extraneous leading directories.

It might sound complicated, but if you change directory to whichever directory contains the files to be patched, you can *usually* just run `patch < fix_compile.diff` or `patch -p1 fix_compile.diff`. I like to *try* applying the patches first, just in case *some* of the patch applies cleanly, and some doesn't:

```
patch --dry-run < fix_compile.diff
```

or

```
patch --dry-run -p1 < fix_compile.diff
```

etc. Once you find one that works, remove the `--dry-run` and apply, compile, and see if you're good to go.

Comment: thanks for the help, I did it by hand and everything compiled without errors.